# Django MPTT duplicate key value violates unique constraint

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, unique-constraint, django-mptt

I practice django-mptt and face problem

Here is my models.py

```
class Genre(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children', db_index=True)
```

I create some data :

- USA

  - NY

    - BuildingA

      - 3F
      - 4F
    - BuildingB

And now,I need to create `4F` under `BuildingB`

```
floor3 = Genre.objects.create(name="3F", parent= buildingB)
```

but face problem  :

```
IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "myapp_genre_name_key"
DETAIL:  Key (name)=(3F) already exists.
```

How can I fix it??

Comment: Do you really need the `unique=True` argument? It's the key of your problem.

Comment: Thank god, your are right !! I originally thought it was because the ````MPTTMeta````:````order_insertion_by = ['name']````. Do you know what is ````order_insertion_by = ['name']````

Comment: It's a default ordering for newly inserted items. If you order them by hand, this option will no be of great help to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my understanding, you want your names to be unique across the building.
To achieve that, remove the `unique=True` from the `name` field declaration and add a Meta option:

```
class Genre(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children', db_index=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('name', 'parent', ), )
```